Happy path logs are not displayed in kibana
I am trying to learn how to send logs, metrics and traces to elastic. I'm using an ASP.NET Web API to create two demo apps: ApiOne and ApiTwo.
I'm using ElasticAPM and Serilog packages.
Here is configuration which is same for both projects (only variables are different):
program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAllElasticApm();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    {
        CustomFormatter = new EcsTextFormatter()
    })
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Services.AddSerilog();

appsettings.json:
{
  "ElasticApm":
  {
    "ServiceName": "ApiOne",
    "ServerUrl":  "http://localhost:8200",
    "SecretToken":  "Secret",
    "TransactionSampleRate": 1.0,
    "Environment": "Development"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using":  [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "ApiOne"
    }
  }
}

The logs appear at kibana only when an exception occurred. Otherwise nothing is displayed. Even custom logs (I am using ILogger) are not displayed.

For example, this error message has never been displayed in kibana.
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger) : ControllerBase
{
    private static int _reqNum = 0;

    [HttpGet("number")]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetNumber()
    {
        var incrementedVal = Interlocked.Increment(ref _reqNum);
        logger.LogInformation("Test Log Text");
        
        return Task.FromResult(Ok(new {Number = Random.Shared.Next(0, 30)}) as IActionResult);
    }
}

What is the problem ? How can I make kibana show these logs?

I think it might be the LogLevel setting. Let's try setting LogLevel to Info.
{
  "ElasticApm": {
    "LogLevel": "Info" 
  }
}


Tried, nothing changed
